# Windows 10 multiple desktops save

Tags: windows-10, desktop-environment

is there a way of saving all desktops states? For example if I open google chrome on my desktop, I move to another desktop (task view -> new desktop) and open some app there too, can I save these opened apps somehow so both the desktops are gonna be in the same state even if I restart pc?

Thank you.